# Nextjs - I can't fetch a cookie credentialed route because of CORS

Tags: express, cookies, next.js, cross-domain

1. Here is the Nextjs hook i use to fetch the route which depends on cookie generated in the same route when logging in

```
useEffect(() => {
        const firstLogin = localStorage.getItem("firstLogin");
        if (firstLogin) {
          const refreshToken = async () => {
            const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/user/refresh-token", {
              method: "GET",
              credentials: "include",
              headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            });
            const tk = await res.json();
            console.log(tk);
          };
          refreshToken();
        }
      }, []);
```

2. Here is the server.js file where i set a middleware to handle CORS options

```
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
    res.setHeader(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
      "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    );
    res.setHeader(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "Content-Type, Authorization, origins"
    );
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
      return res.status(200);
    }
  
    next();
  });
```

So my Question is: When I log in the cookie is generated and Sent to `user/refresh-token` and then i get redirect ed to the `/` page and then i use `useEffect()` to get request the `user/refresh-token` but it gives me an error that get request failed because there is no cookie is Sent to the route.

Comment: And what is not working for you?

Comment: When I log in the cookie is generated and Sent to user/refresh-token and then i get redirect ed to the / page and then i use useEffect() to get request the user/refresh-token but it gives me an error that get request failed because there is no cookie is Sent to the route